# VBA in Publisher - Execute Macro on Keystroke

Tags: vba, ms-publisher

I'm working within Microsoft Publisher.

I have a macro in module1 (that works) called "Export_as_Image".

I want to run this macro whenever I press F8.

I have created module2 with this code:

```
Sub SetKey()
Application.OnKey "{F8}", "Export_as_Image"
End Sub
```

When I run module2 I recieve the error "Compile error: Method or data member not found".

When I press F8 within Publisher, nothing happens.

Can anyone suggest what I may have done wrong, or a code to help me achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: After more searching, it seems that OnKey is not available within Publisher. Does anybody know of a work-around for this?

Comment: I don't think there's a way in Publisher to use that key. You would have to add Export_as_image to your ribbon or quick access and use the built-in keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I found that it's needed to run `SetKey` for the first time firstly. You may call it from an event-driven sub (`Workbook_Open`, for example). Looks like running it for the first time, registers the key shortcut to the specified code.

Also, add the full path to the code you need to run: `"Module2.Export_as_Image"`.

**Update (reply to Charlie's comment below)**

You can even move `SetKey`'s code to `Workbook_Open` and delete `SetKey` (see image below).

[image: Run on open]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Would you be able to show me how to call SetKey using Workbook_Open?

Thanksagain

Comment: @Charlie, I've updated my reply to your comment.

Comment: BTW, [this tutorial](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/) explains Excel VBA Events basics (this should be of great help for solving your task).

Comment: i tried in publisher, but not working...i wrong something??

Comment: I don't know Publisher at all. Anyway, make sure you use proper object and event names.